# How to add a custom row(header) to a List component of Sencha

Tags: salesforce-id, community, mobile, touch, salesforce-sencha

I have a Page that renders a list of records from a store. I am using "List" component for displaying it. The list would display one account, one contact and one opportunity in each row. I need to add a header to the list. I want something like this

Account     Contact     Opportunity
 in the header so that we can understand what is displayed in list. How to achieve? Any suggestions?
 Edit: I am really sorry for the trouble I caused. I am developing a Sencha application. I am using a Sencha "List"(xtype) for displaying data.

Comment: Which "List" component are you referring to? Is it a custom component utilizing standard apex:pageBlockTable component? If so, just add headerValue attribute for each of your apex:column components.

Comment: Your tag selection is confusing, is it really sencha related? Is it a Visualforce page or something else? Can you post some pieces of your code (we don't know whether you're using apex:pageBlockTable, apex:dataTable, apex:repeat or what).

Comment: I am really sorry for the trouble I caused. I am developing a Sencha application. I am using a Sencha "List"(xtype) for displaying data.

Answer (score 0):

A list component isn't going to have multiple columns like you're after.

The [grid component](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Grid) however does. You'll need to configure the columns property which should handle rendering a header for you as well. Something like:

```
columns: [
    {
        text: 'Account',
        dataIndex: 'accountid'
    },
    {
        text: 'Contact',
        dataIndex: 'contactid'
    },
    {
        text: 'Opportunity',
        dataIndex: 'opportunityid'
    }
]
```